# Is is allowed to move the argument to the right or left of the Lambda Term?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

[image: Can it work like this ?]

When can we move the argument to the right of the lambda term? To the right of the bracket. In what scenarios it is allowed?

Comment: Never, really. Unless you are switching notation, e.g. from an `add` function call to infix `+` operator. What is this `x` in your picture?

Comment: Its just a variable I suppose.

Comment: Then the movement is wrong. What makes you think these terms are equivalent? Try with some example values.

Comment: Why do you think this would ever be valid, other than by coincidence (e.g., like [anomalous cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_cancellation) is)?

Comment: @Bergi I will share the full question (Please take a look ), can you verify if it's correct and check if the operation is valid. [link to the question](https://imgur.com/a/UuSyPMz)

Comment: @Skywalker No, it's not correct. It's not know what `x` is.

Comment: In fact you can apply η-conversion to `λuv.buv`⇒`b`, then the result is `λabc.a(xcb)`.

Comment: @Bergi How can you apply η-conversion to `λuv.buv⇒b `  `b` is not a lambda function , further more I don't think  η-conversion applies to variables and constants

Comment: @Skywalker How do you know `b` is not a lambda function? It's applied with arguments `u` and `v`, isn't it?

Comment: @Bergi It  is not specifically mentioned what b is but as far as I know it is a free variable